# Why isn't this ajax:success call working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know there's a ton of threads about this, but I can't seem to figure out what's broken here. I have a remote link that calls a like method.

When I click the like link...

**What's happens:**

- The `like` is created (as expected).
- The page does not refresh (as expected).

**What should happen:**

- Everything above, plus the content change in `like.js.erb`. I've added a console.log to this file and it does not show up when clicking the like link.

**_like.html.erb**

```
<% recipe = recipe || @recipe %>
<%= link_to unlike_recipe_path(recipe), remote: true, class: "recipe-card__like like" do %>
  <i class="heart icon"></i>
<% end %>
```

note: the partial is rendered both on a show page and within an index, which is why I use the || statement.

**like.js.erb**

```
$('.like').bind('ajax:success', function(){
  console.log('like clicked');
  $(this).closest('.like').hide();
  $(this).closest('.like-container').html('<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'unlike', recipe: @recipe ) %>');
});
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :recipes do
    resources :likes

    member do
      get "/like", to: "recipes#like"
    end
  end
```

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
  def like
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @like = @recipe.likes.create(recipe_id: @recipe.id, user_id: current_user["uid"])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require semantic-ui/sidebar
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: try `$('.recipe-card__like.like')` or better just remove `.bind` line no need it also. Probably it's not form thats why u cant check fail or success.

Comment: I just added a `console.log` outside of the `.bind` function and that is being called, so the file is definitely getting noticed. How would I do this without the `.bind` function?

Comment: the moment you `.bind('ajax:succeed')` is already to late because this file is indeed the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways using JS/Html/Ajax.

```
#like.js.erb
#if wanna validate the request success or fail use @like
# just make sure @like is not string type otherwise it will always success in JS file.
if("<%= @like %>"){
    console.log('like clicked');
    $(this).closest('.like').hide();
    $(this).closest('.like-container').html('<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'unlike', recipe: @recipe ) %>');
}
```

Also, in controller no need `recipe_id: @recipe.id`. It's supposed to assign automatically.

`@like = @recipe.likes.create(user_id: current_user["uid"])`

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in comment, the moment you `.bind('ajax:succeed')` is already to late because this file is indeed the result. Your `erb` file will be filled before rendering the output so you could do

```
<% if @result == "success" %>
  console.log('like clicked')
  $(this).closest('.like').hide();
  $(this).closest('.like-container').html('<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'unlike', recipe: @recipe ) %>');
<% else %>
  console.log('something went wrong, this person has to many likes')
<% end %>
```

where `@result` is your controller variable

Comment: I replaced my `like.js.erb` with your code, and that triggered the else state twice. edit: hold on, need to add @result to my controller.

Comment: Do you have any other events handlers in your javascript ?

Comment: Okay, so how the correct console message is displaying (still twice, though), but the content still isn't changing. Without the bind event, I no longer have a reference class to assign to $(this)

Comment: by @result I ment `@like.is_present ?` or something of course.

Comment: I think `jquery_ujs` in your `applications.js` can cause the problem of triggering twice. rails_ujs replace jquery_ujs functionality

Comment: Removing jquery_ujs did fix the double trigger - thanks for that! The correct console message is firing, but the content still isn't updating. Recognizing this is just an issue with how the js is written, but how could I identify which like on the page to swap out without any known what $(this) is now?

Comment: Since you have `recipe.id` you could put it into `html attribute` and then in respond by this `id` you could find this field by jquery

Comment: like this `$(".like[data-myid='" + <%= recipe.id %> + "']");`

Comment: Well, I just found a bigger issue haha. My link was calling the `unlike` not `like` method. Everything was all crossed after that.

Comment: pleasure to help. Please accept the anwser I need points for bounty for my code issues :D

Comment: If you copy & paste my own answer, I'll accept it as the correct one to give you points.

Comment: So does it work with `.bind ajax:success` ? No need to do circus to gain points

Comment: Yep, all that needed to change was to call the correct method haha

Comment: now i can see that your approach is diffrent than I thought it is. I would render _create_like.js.erb without html and I wouldn't have to listen to ajax success. but on contrary your `like.html`, `like.js` keeps code in more readable way.

Answer (score 0):

My link was calling the `unlike` method instead of the `like` method. Simple typo.

**Original**

```
<% recipe = recipe || @recipe %>
<%= link_to unlike_recipe_path(recipe), remote: true, class: "recipe-card__like like" do %>
  <i class="heart icon"></i>
<% end %>
```

**What it should be**

```
<% recipe = recipe || @recipe %>
<%= link_to like_recipe_path(recipe), remote: true, class: "recipe-card__like like" do %>
  <i class="heart icon"></i>
<% end %>
```